# Python how to correct a misaligned substring position info from string

Tags: python, text, nlp, data-preprocessing

I have a list of strings and the start offset and end offset of substrings that need to be used for training a nlp model.
Some of these positions for substring are misaligned. Eg:

```
text = 'Car is blue'  
start_offset = 0  
end_offset = 2  #misaligned. should be 3.  
substring = text[start_offset:end_offset] # should be 'Car' but misaligned to give substring as 'Ca'
```

The aim is to check if substring highlighted is a whole word from the whole string. If not, correct the start and end offset.
What python code could I use to get whole word substrings?

Comment: `text.split()`?

Comment: @Grismar. after text.split() how could I see if position of substring given is of a whole word? Could you help?

Comment: `text[start_offset:end_offset] in text.split()` - it doesn't appear you're trying very hard. Can you explain what the actual problem is you're trying to resolve? Because the problem you've asked about seems both trivial and pointless? I'm guessing it's supposed to provide a solution to a more meaningful problem?

Comment: @Grismar I have been given list of thousands of texts with 2 positions pointing towards a substring in that text. These substrings are used to train a Named Entrity recognition model. 
The problem is that, sometime the start and end positions given are not pointing towards the whole word in the text. These misaligned texts cannot be used by the model for training.
Thus, I wanted to write a code that could check if the start and end positions given point towards a whole word in the string, If not, the code would check the position to the correct number.
This would then be used for training.

Comment: If the matches are only ever off by one (on either side), you could simply use `.split` and check that `text[start_offset-1:end_offset+1].strip()` is in them, or even just use that assuming it is correct, given that you would at most be including whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `end_offset + 1`. Range selectors on strings are inclusive of the first element and exclusive of the last, so the letter "r" on index "2" in this case is not taken. If you want the whole word, the range should be 0:3.

Comment: I know that. I have mentioned it in the #comment. The problem is that there are thousands of texts. The substring to be highlight could be anywhere in the whole string. I won't be able to check any manually. I wanted help in a code that would help in correcting the offsets on its own.